# Ag-grid : Dynamicaly update gridOption callback- getDatapath() when treedata=true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

**Use case** : We have an use case to toggle between client side treedata mode and normal mode .
**Issue** : TreeData is initially set to false and upon toggle it is set to true but the callback passed in gridOption for getDatapath() never gets called when treedata is updated to true
**Rootcause** : dynamic update to gridOption is not supported

**Solutions tried**: call gridApi.redrawRows() or gridApi.refreshCells() after updating rowData. But both solutions did not work.
**Expectations** : when treeData is set to true, getDatapath () call back has to be called ie., Alternative way to Dynamicaly update gridOption

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.